# Traverse - Go up to closest and find down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I want to get the selected value of `dropdown-menu` and apply it to the `span` of `dropdown_text`

```
<div class='dropdown'>
    <button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle col-sm-12' style='border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px; type='button' id='dropdownMenu1' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true'>
        <span class='dropdown_text'>Choose a option</span>
        <span class='caret'></span>
    </button>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu1'>
        <li><a href='#'>Yes</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>No</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried this with no success:

```
    $('.dropdown-menu li > a').click(function(event){
        var otherInput = $(this).closest('button').find('span');
        console.log(otherInput);

        //$('.dropdown_text').text(this.innerHTML);  <<<<---- 
    });
```

The one with the arrow works, but because I have multiple instances of the `<div class='dropdown'>`, dynamically created, I need to apply the value not to ALL of them, but just the "current" one.

So I thought. from the slelected `a` I traverse up to the `closest` button and `find` the element with class `dropdown_text`.

But I seem to be doing something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `button` is not an *ancestor* of the `li > a` - so `closest()` will not work - instead find `dropdown` using `closest()` and then *descent* to find `button span`.

See code below:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li > a').click(function(event){
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('button span.dropdown_text').text(this.innerHTML);
});
```

See demo below:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li > a').click(function(event){
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('button span.dropdown_text').text(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='dropdown'>
  <button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle col-sm-12' style='border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;' type='button' id='dropdownMenu1' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true'>
    <span class='dropdown_text'>Choose a option</span>
    <span class='caret'></span>
  </button>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu1'>
    <li><a href='#'>Yes</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>No</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, this works fine except that it applies the answer to `<span class='caret'></span>` aswell. Thanks, this is a good push.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

- get the first parent div with class dropdown: closest('div.dropdown')
- find the span with class dropdown_text: find('span.dropdown_text')

The snippet:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li > a').on('click', function(event){
  var otherInput = $(this).closest('div.dropdown').find('span.dropdown_text');
  console.log(otherInput.text());
  otherInput.text(this.textContent);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class='dropdown'>
    <button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle col-sm-12' style='border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;' type='button' id='dropdownMenu1' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true'>
    <span class='dropdown_text'>Choose a option</span>
    <span class='caret'></span>
    </button>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu1'>
        <li><a href='#'>Yes</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>No</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the `.on('click'` reminder for the dynamic items.

Comment: @morne It's not only for dynamic but especially because with jQuery 3.x.... it's better to use on instead of click. This in order to avoid confusion for instance between window on load and ajax load.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

replace your jQuery code with below code:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.dropdown-menu li > a',function(){
    var value=$(this).html();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.dropdown_text').html(value);

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

$.closest() traverses up the DOM tree.  It doesn't match siblings.  In your click, it will go, li -> ul.dropdown-menu -> div.dropdown -> whatever is its parent.

It will never find the button.

```
var otherInput = $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('span');
```

would return both spans